# Send complex paramater ( array of objects ) to stored proc

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures

I'm trying to implement these parameter structure and send them to stored proc these request dto structure

```
{
  "Action": "Add",
  "FileType": "Mudad",
  "docName": "File.csv",
  "docExtention": "User\\documents\\File.csv",
  "Content": "file.csv (7 MB)",
  "Metadata": {
    "Key": "string",
    "Value": "string"
  }
}
```

I tried many solution and I don't know which solution are good

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.MetaDataList AS TABLE 
(
    keyName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    KeyValue NVARCHAR(MAX),
    PRIMARY KEY (keyName)
)
GO

/*
DECLARE @MetadataValues MetaDataList;

INSERT INTO @MetadataValues VALUES('FileNumber', '012332546')
INSERT INTO @MetadataValues VALUES('unifiedNationalNumber', '70023455436')
INSERT INTO @MetadataValues VALUES('YearMonth', '202401')

EXEC [dbo].[md]
    @FileType = 'csv',
    @docName = 'C:\Test',
    @docExtension = 'csv',
    @ContentBase64 = 'bGFib3JPZmZpY2VJZCxzZXF1ZW5jZU51bWJlcix1bml==',
    @Metadata = @MetadataValues
*/

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[md]
    @FileType NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @docName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @docExtension NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @ContentBase64 VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Metadata MetaDataList READONLY
```

here using table value function but I will face a problem that key and value would be static value

Another way I don't know its valid or not

```
DECLARE @Metadata NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[{ "keyName": "FileNumber", "KeyValue": "012332546" }, , { "keyName": "YearMonth", "KeyValue": "202401" }]'
```

I want to do the logic inside the stored proc but this is first time to handle such parameter to stored proc.

```
*Metadata Array of object
*Key String   Allowed key: FileNumber,Id,Year,Month
*Value String
```

Comment: The content of the `@Metadata` parameter is in JSON format. You may pass this content as `nvarchar(max)` and parse it appropriately with `OPENJSON()`.

Comment: *Why* are you doing this? What does the stored procedure actually do? You can't use arrays or complexe objects in *most* databases and in the vast majority of cases, you don't have to. The relational model is *more* flexible than the *hierarchical* model you try to use here, even if nowadays it's called document or object-based. Relational databases work on entire sets of objects at a time, not a single item

Comment: The "metadata" element for example is problematic in both JSON and relationonal forms. You don't need a `key:value` pair in JSON, the "objects" are actually dictionaries. Key/value tables are a bad design in relational databases too, especially in SQL Server where you can have up to 30K sparse columns per table. That `content` will take a lot more space as BAS64, result in a huge JSON string that's hard to parse. You could just store it to a `varbinary(max)` field instead. Never mind that a file with a `.csv` extension should be imported to an easily queryable table, not treated as a blob